# Azure B2C - Bypass SocialLogin Provider Selection

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

does anyone know if there is a way to bypass the Azure B2C Social Login selection page and redirect the user directly to one of the Social Provider login page.

I have an Azure B2C tenant with a custom policy, multiple social login provider such as Google, Microsoft Personal and Microsoft Work.
We have the requirement to redirect some users directly to Google login page instead to the B2C page where they can select one.

Not sure if there is any special URL/URL parameter that allows this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing an extra query parameter (using extraQueryParameters) to b2c login page, and then from login page template I use jQuery/javascript to automatically redirect the user.